# Debian : Encrypted Raid 1 setup.

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, encryption, raid

We have a Debian X64 server which has the following config. One single 512GB SSD, which has our OS and two 2.0TB HDD's which have data like attachments, etc.

The two 2.0 TB drives are in RAID-1 configuration. For security purposes, I would like to encrypt this RAID-1 setup. The thing I don't understand is, even the encrypted drive will require a key to decrypt. These are the two problems I am having :

1. How to setup an encrypted RAID-1. I found a lot of stuff for RAID with LVM.
2. Where and how will the key be stored for decrypting the drive.

Here is my raid config :

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Feb  2 16:35:52 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953382336 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382336 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Feb 11 10:00:37 2016
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : domain:0  (local to host domain)
           UUID : e3750654:c7e1a24c:3f0a15b6:46f26d0d
         Events : 22

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypting the filesystem is not as secure as full partition encryption, and arguably harder to use - as well as slower.

The typical way to set up encryption would be to set up RAID1, Then LVM, Then Encrypt to LVM volume.  (You could skip the LVM volume bit, but it adds more flexibility).  I would imagine that most distros will allow you to do this on a fresh install - This is true of [Ubuntu/Mint](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu) and, if you want to switch the [LVM and Encryption layers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1935300) here.  I'm pretty sure you can do this with Redhat and derivitives as well.

As far as storing the key - Full Disk encryption uses [LUKS](https://guardianproject.info/code/luks/), so the key is stored in the header of the disk, and encrypted with your passphrase.  This means you can change your passphrase without needing to re-encrypt the disk.

When running an encrypted FS you need to re-enter the key each time you boot up.  (If you use Ubuntu user encryption, this is not the case - it takes the key from the users password - and its also less secure).

**Extended information after Comments**

As you have built the RAID 1 array, the first step is to build LVM on top of it.  You should google for it to fully understand it, but there are 3 parts to this -

1. Use the command `pvcreate /dev/md0` makes the RAID device an LVM
   resource.
2. Add a volume group with the command `vgcreate RaidVG /dev/md0`
3. Create a Logical Volume using a command like `lvcreate -n LVMVol RaidVG -L +1700G` (Its a good idea to ensure the Logical Volume is smaller then the full disk size so you can do snapshots and other cool stuff)

This will create a new volume (similar to a partition) called `/dev/RaidVG/LVMVol`, which you would then encrypt.  To do this  use the command `cryptsetup -u u-v luksFormat /dev/RaidVG/LVMVol`  to create the volume.

To mount the volume (and you will need to run this command every time you restart the system), type `cryptsetup luksOpen  /dev/RaidVG/LVMVol CryptVol` - This will ask you to enter a password and then create a new volume/partition `/dev/mapper/CryptVol` which you can operate on - and all operations will be encrypted.

After this its a matter of creating the filesystem - eg `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/CryptVol`, and then mounting it `mount /dev/mapper/CryptVol /path/to/mountpoint`  - You will, of-course, need to manually mount the volume each time you restart the computer, after unencrypting it first as above.

Comment: Cannot do a fresh-install myself, server is located in different geographical region. Also, the OS does not boot from the drive/FS which I am planning to encrpyt. LVM with RAID sounds nice, I agree with that. I have already taken backup of the HD, so I can erase it. Can you tell me how I can proceed with RAID1-LVM. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information, I will go through the setup after some research on LVM.  Is there some reason I cannot add entry for it in fstab, as the password is already entered, so by the time boot is complete, the drive must be available.

Comment: Just one thing, command cryptsetup is throwing an error, with unknwon option -u. Is something wrong with the command you gave?

Comment: I just used this command instead of that : cryptsetup -v luksFormat <device> . It worked then. Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Can you please format the text of commands properly, so other user's will find it easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How to setup an encrypted RAID-1.

Easiest way: Set up an unencryped RAID 1 and encrypt the filesystem. (No the disk or the partition).

I never did this myself, but it seems one way to do it is:

- cryptsetup options luksFormat device
- cryptsetup open device name
- mkfs.fstype /dev/mapper/name  (which is done on the encrypted device)

> Where and how will the key be stored for decrypting the drive.

Ah, good question. The answer should be 'nowhere on the computer'.
Else it is similar to a lock with the key still inserted.

You will need to manually enter the key on each time you boot.

Apparently you can also store it in /etc/crypttab, but then your security is significanly less. It will prevent someone from just physically removing the disks and reading the contents. But if they can access the disks then they probably also can access your SSD and retrieve the keys.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. After the command mdadm.create and providing both the devices, I gave the command mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0. This is where I created the file-system for the RAID-array. Should I do something else instead of this for creating an encrypted FS? Kindly let me know.

Comment: Added the command needed to the post. Note that I never did this on real hardware (so davids performance issue are probably relevant).

Comment: @Henny - you might want to remove the bit of your response about filesystem encryption - our solutions are essentially the same and are block device/partition level solutions. File level solutions do exist but are known to be comparably insecure (cryptfs)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a RAID in place already in `/dev/md0`. Check it using:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

If you see something like `md0 : active raid1 sdc[1] sda[0]` you are good to go:

```
sudo cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/md0
```

Open it

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 my_raid
```

Check for size

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/my_raid
```

Create file system

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_raid
```

Mount it

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_raid /mnt/my_raid
```

Check it

```
df -h | grep raid
```

Here is our encrypted, mounted raid:

`/dev/mapper/my_raid  3.6T   89M  3.4T   1% /mnt/my_raid`

tada.